# How to check when ios device just lost connection to internet

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

how to detect losing connection to network as fast as it can be

now im using reachabitity framework for swift and it takes abouut 3 sec to detect that there is no network so user can make the app crash

here how i check it :

```
func setupReachability() {
    do {
        self.reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    } catch {
        print("Cannot setup reachability monitoring")
        return
    }

    self.reachability!.whenReachable = { reachability in
        self.loginButton(true)
    }
    self.reachability!.whenUnreachable = { reachability in
        self.loginButton(false)
    }

    do { try self.reachability!.startNotifier() } catch {
        print("Cannot start reachability monitoring")
        return
    }

    print("Started reachability")
}
```

Comment: You have to make use of error handling in your requests and not just blindly believe your user has always internet. Reachability isn't that fast (what you discovered). But the error is in your requests logic, not in the Reachability, because their internet can change in the middle of the request and you will crash anyways.

Comment: will do some error handling, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You always, ALWAYS, must handle errors in your connections. You absolutely *cannot* rely on Reachability. You also cannot rely that your connection goes to the server that you *want* to connect to. It is possible and practically happens a lot that you get a reply from a totally different server in a totally different format than you expected, and you need to handle that. (Take your app to the nearest Starbucks and check whether it survives).